# Error when compiling by command-line a .cpp program

Tags: c++, g++

My .cpp program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << 5;
    return 0;
}
```

I have Windows 8, and gcc version 3.4.2 (I need this one due to didactics reasons)

When I do at line command: g++ prova.cpp, it returns this error:

```
g++: Internal error: Aborted (program collect2)
Please submit a full bug report.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is it because of Windows 8?

nb. When I do for example: g++ -c prova.cpp it works!

Comment: It is not immediately obvious what is wrong here. Since `-c` means "Compile only" it is likely the linker step that fails. Do you have write access to the output directory ?

Comment: @driis: Actually, the reference to `collect2`, the linker used by `gcc`, it says even in the message that the linker fails, just in a somewhat awkward way. What causes this error, however, I don't know.

Comment: What you're doing wrong is using a really old version of g++.  Upgrade and the problem will probably go away.

Comment: My Teacher said something about that with old versions of gcc we have to write some "_" before some function. I didn't remember that... Could be important?

Comment: There are several generations of newer gcc than 3.4.2. I'm not sure if it's a windows 8 thing, or something else, but getting a newer version will probably help. Is there not a bit more message with "please submit a full bug report"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An internal error means that the compiler has a bug.

You could do what the error message says and submit a bug report. However, because you are using such an ancient version of GCC, I expect that would be fruitless.